# Where does pip look for wheel files?

Tags: python, pip, python3

I want to install [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) with pip:`pip install tensorflow` as shown on the original site but i got error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

So I tried to download wheel file from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) and tried `pip install tensorflow.whl` and got error:

> Requirement 'tensorflow.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
>   tensorflow.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

How I see it, it means that file isn't in directory pip searches in.
Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong or where to move file so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why `pip install tensorflow` failed, I cannot tell. Maybe you are behind a firewall? Or there could be environment variables named `PIP_*` that affect its behavior.

The wheels for tensorflow from PyPI have names such as `tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`. If you download and install one, then keep the filename, and tell pip exactly where the file is located. For example

```
pip install ./downloads/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

As the second part of the error message indicates, `tensorflow.whl` is not a valid filename for a wheel package. It's missing all the extra information from the original filename. I guess you chose a simple filename when downloading, but that doesn't work with wheels.